# What is the easiest way to wrap a standard library object and only override a single method?

Tags: java

Suppose I need a Map object that behaves like HashMap with the exception of a single method in HashMap. Do I really need to implement every single method asked for by the Map interface?:

```
public WrappedMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>{
    public HashMap<K, V> hm;

    public WrappedMap<K, V>(){
        hm = new HashMap<K, V>();
    }

    //implement clear(), containsKey(.) etc.
}
```

Even though I can simply hit `hm` with the required methods (except the one method that needs to be changed from default behavior), it is still laborious to have to list every required Map interface method.

Is there a shortcut?

Comment: Why not just extend `HashMap` and override the method you want?

Comment: Why don't you use subclassing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply extend the HashMap class and override the methods that you'd like to add new logic to.

You may be interested to find out a bit more about [Inheritance vs. Composition](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html), which might give you a few tips on whether you are better off extending a HashMap, or using composition to delegate to one - depending on your use case.

When it comes to composotion, there's no "easy" way using plain-old-java to simply override a couple of methods. However, you might consider using Project Lombok. It has an annotation called `@Delegate` that does exactly this. You can find more information in the [Lombok Documentation](http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can create your wrapper that extends HashMap and override the method you want.
In that way you don;t have to implement each method

Comment: You could, but inheritance can often lead to subtle problems, and is harder to test then a composition approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- extend an already existing class java.util.HashMap
- extend a simple abstract class like [java.util.AbstractMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html) and implement the missing method
- use a java.lang.reflect.Proxy wrapping the original class.